# PhantomJS: setContent not working when HTML has assets

Tags: html, phantomjs

This script works:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); 

var html = '<h1>Test</h1><img>'; //works with page.setContent and page.content
//var html = '<h1>Test</h1><img src=".">'; //only works with page.content

page.setContent(html, 'http://github.com');
//page.content = html;

page.render('test.png');
phantom.exit();
```

but adding a `src` attribute to the `img` makes it fail silently (`page.render` returns `false` and no image is generated).

Setting `page.content` directly works in both cases but then relative URLs don't. The same thing happens with other tags that load a resource such as `link`. It doesn't matter whether the linked resource exists or not. Tested in 1.8.1 and 1.9.2.

Is this a bug or have I misunderstood the API?

Comment: Posted as an issue over at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11656

Answer (score 4):

*You can not render webpage if it is not fully loaded.*

When you are setting link or `src` to `<img>`, It will try to load image asynchronously.
So, it requires to wait for loading finished.

Try following code.

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    page.render('test.png');
    phantom.exit();
};
page.setContent(html, 'http://github.com');
```

Comment: It isn't called at all if webpages are created in a for-loop it seems. I was unable to do a batch conversion of SVG to PNG with your approach, although it worked perfectly for a single file.

Comment: @CoDEmanX: For batch processing you can always call you own function say `loadNextSVG()` instead `phantom.exit()` which sets newer SVG context in page and same `onLoadFinished` will be called to proceed to next SVG. Such a way creating a loop without for-loop. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it does work indeed. I need to use global variables however, to pass information on to the `onLoadFinished` callback (output file name needed for `page.render()`). Furthermore, it becomes tricky to skip invalid files returned by `listdir()`, as in code gets messy due to the recursive approach.

Comment: With Phantom 2.0.0, I found that the url HAS to start with a protcol. Like `http://` or `file://` or else remote file requests are simply not triggered.